# React: useState is not resetting to initial state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to re-render the checked state of below component, even though the isChecked state comes as false, the useState is not updating to the set prop value, instead it maintains the old state.

```
const CheckListItem = ({ label, onChangeEventHandler, isChecked, index }) => {
  const [checked, setChaecked] = useState(isChecked || false);
  console.log(`${label} checked => `, isChecked); \\ false
  console.log(`${label} checked => `, checked); \\ true || maintaining the old state.
  const localOnChangeHandler = (ev) => {
    if (typeof onChangeEventHandler === "function") {
      setChaecked(ev.target.checked);
      onChangeEventHandler(index, ev.target.checked);
    }
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`in useEffect ${label} checked => `, isChecked);
    setChaecked(isChecked);
  }, [isChecked, label]);

  return (
    <li key={index}>
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={checked}
          onChange={localOnChangeHandler}
        />
        {label}
      </label>
    </li>
  );
};
```

`checked` should have the correct value which is set in the `isChecked` prop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`useState` is working as intended, the value passed to it is only its `initialState` and if even if that value changes it will not update the stored value.

See React's docs about [Resetting all state when a prop changes](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#resetting-all-state-when-a-prop-changes) - rather than complicate your code you can pass a `key` from the parent to create a new component instance and thereby pass a new `initialState`:

```js
<CheckListItem
  initialIsChecked={initialIsChecked}
  {/* When `initialIsChecked` changes, a new
    * `CheckListItem` instance will be created` */}
  key={initialIsChecked}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a typo in `setChaecked(ev.target.checked);` change it to `setChecked(ev.target.checked);`

And also try this code

```
const CheckListItem = ({ label, onChangeEventHandler, isChecked, index }) => {
  const localOnChangeHandler = (ev) => {
    if (typeof onChangeEventHandler === "function") {
      onChangeEventHandler(index, ev.target.checked);
    }
  };

  return (
    <li key={index}>
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={isChecked}
          onChange={localOnChangeHandler}
        />
        {label}
      </label>
    </li>
  );
};
```

Comment: Could be a typo or not, it does not affect the functionality in this case.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thank you for the latest contribution.

Comment: Thanks, by this it will always stick to the isChecked prop value, and will never change to newer value.